# How do you hide a UI object (Video Player) after time (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video-player

I am very new to using Unity and I am surviving off tutorials from YouTube. As soon as my game is launched, a video is started using Video Player. I am hoping to make the video hidden after the video has finished playing to reveal my menu screen. I do have a script that I have used to hide the video player

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HideVideo : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject VideoPlayer;
public void HideVideoPlayer()
{
    VideoPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

The problem is, the closest I have gotten to actually hiding my video is by setting it to an onclick event via a button. How do I make the video player hide after the video is finished playing? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `VideoPlayer.isPlaying` ? if you are not looping the video you can use this or you can use `VideoPlayer.loopPointReached`

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply hide it, when it stops playing and put it in Update?

```
void Update() {
    if (!(VideoPlayer.isPlaying)) {
        VideoPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

A complete script could be look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HideVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject VideoPlayer;
    public bool isPlayerStarted = false;

    void Update() {
        if (isPlayerStarted == false && VideoPlayer.IsPlaying == true) {
            // When the player is started, set this information
            isPlayerStarted = true;
        }
        if (isPlayerStarted == true && VideoPlayer.isPlaying == false ) {
            // Wehen the player stopped playing, hide it
            VideoPlayer.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }   
}
```